# Symfony2 formbuilder choice field labels translating, values do not

Tags: php, forms, symfony, internationalization, formbuilder

So, this WAS working correctly, until my last composer.phar update... My code hasn't changed, but obviously something else has. In my formbuilder, I have multiple option fields, and all of the fields (for the entire form) are translated. The labels for all option fields are translating and displaying correctly, however none of the values are being translated. Here's the form Type code snippets:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
$builder-> //...
  ->add('size_length','number', array(
    'label' => 'block.length',
    'max_length' => 50,
    'required' => false,
    'attr' => array(
       'placeholder' => '123...' )
  ))
  ->add('size_length_units','choice', array(
    'empty_value' => 'block.units.select',
    'choices'   => array(
      'block.units.millimeters' => 'block.units.millimeters',
      'block.units.centimeters' => 'block.units.centimeters',
      'block.units.meters'      => 'block.units.meters',
      'block.units.kilometers'  => 'block.units.kilometers',
      'block.units.inches'      => 'block.units.inches',
      'block.units.feet'        => 'block.units.feet',
      'block.units.yards'       => 'block.units.yards',
      'block.units.miles'       => 'block.units.miles',
      'block.units.furlongs'    => 'block.units.furlongs',
      'block.units.rods'        => 'block.units.rods'),
    'label' => 'block.length.units',
    'required' => false,
    'multiple' => false
    ));
}

/**
 * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
 */

public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class' => 'My\Entity\Block',
        'translation_domain' => 'block',
        'cascade_validation' => true
    ));
}
```

Here's what the HTML looks like:

```
<select id="blockEditForm_size_length_units" name="blockEditForm[size_length_units]">
<option value="">(Units)</option>
<option value="block.units.millimeters">Millimeters</option>
<option value="block.units.centimeters">Centimeters</option>
<option value="block.units.meters">Meters</option>
<option value="block.units.kilometers">Kilometers</option>
<option value="block.units.inches">Inches</option>
<option value="block.units.feet">Feet</option>
<option value="block.units.yards">Yards</option>
<option value="block.units.miles">Miles</option>
<option value="block.units.furlongs">Furlongs</option>
<option value="block.units.rods">Rods</option>
</select>
```

Any ideas? Again, this was all working before (both labels and options were being translated correctly). Now, it is only the labels, not the values. I have this occurring on multiple forms and in multiple choice fields within the same form (same units are often used). Would appreciate any ideas or insights anyone has.

Comment: do you have a list of what packages were updated from your update?

Comment: I could pull it, but I also added 4 new packages with the update (hence the reason for the overall update), so given kix' points below, I may just rewrite the process and schema (as recommended).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, technically as of [Symfony 2.0](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/21cec043d72a2c5c63599d47bd4f742b2b992f6e/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L37), values were not passed through the translator. And there were no changes since that could have introduced such behaviour.

Actually, option values should not be passed through the translator, because they are about data and business logic, not user experience. Perhaps, you should replace the placeholder keys in your choices array with something more concise, like `'millimeters', 'centimeters'` etc.

However, if for some strange reason you'll need these values to be translated (I can't really imagine such a case, but let's assume there is one), you could try overriding the [`choice_widget_options` block](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/form_div_layout.html.twig#L90) in Symfony 2's `form_div_layout.html.twig`, like this:

```
{% block choice_widget_options %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% for group_label, choice in options %}
        {% if choice is iterable %}
            <optgroup label="{{ group_label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}">
                {% set options = choice %}
                {{ block('choice_widget_options') }}
            </optgroup>
        {% else %}
            <option value="{{ choice.value|trans({}, translation_domain) }}"{% if choice is selectedchoice(value) %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>{{ choice.label|trans({}, translation_domain) }}</option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock choice_widget_options %}
```

For more info on overriding form templates you can check out [Symfony 2's official documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#what-are-form-themes).

Comment: kix, thanks. I was hoping to avoid using the Twig template to do the translating, but it might be the better solution. The units don't actually fit into the business logic in this specific application, hence the desire to have them persisted simply to display back to the user when they're working through items. However, that might be better handled differently as well.

Comment: The reasons are very obvious. The data is meaningless to a user. They need translating. In 3.1 you can use 'choice_translation_domain' to translate the drop down values from a join BUT there doesnt seem a way to translate the labels added vai formbuilder.add()